# Pasting over a filtered table

Tags: excel, filter, copy-paste

Is there a way to copy filtered data from a table in one workbook to another workbook with the exact same table with the same filter applied, but only copy and paste the visible cells? I know of some ways to do this within the same workbook with formulas but can't figure this out.

Comment: This, along with the answer provided are both valid options. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, this is possible.**  You will need to SORT both filtered list so that the data you want to paste is in the same order.  In order to do this, you will need to add a new column to both lists.  This column will be used to identify which rows you wish to copy, and make sure that they're all in sequence when you paste.

**Here are the steps:**

1. Let's use this as an example sheet:  [image: Starting List Example]
2. Add a New Column to both of your lists... this column will be our way of sorting and controlling the filtered copy/paste behavior.  [image: Create New Column]
3. Apply the Filters you need to both lists...  [image: Apply your Filters]
4. Add data to the New Column, in this example, I used 'x'.  You can double click the bottom right corner of the cell to make it fill in all the displayed cells. [image: Add data to your new column] [image: Fill in all rows]
5. Okay, now turn off all the filters for both lists.  [image: Turn off filters]
6. Sort both lists by the New Column... 
   [image: Sort by New Column]
7. Filter via the New Column, and begin your copy/paste operations!
   [image: Filter by New Column, now ready for copy/pasting!]

**Steps without pictures:**

1. Add a column to both list.  This column will be blank for now.
2. Set your filters on both list to be identical.
3. Once you are satisfied with your filters, start adding data to the new column we added in step 1.  For example, I put in `x`, and then I double click the lower right box selection thingy so that the `x` fills in all the (filtered) rows.  Do this on both lists.
4. Now remove the filters for both list, and then sort by the new column that we created.  Make it so that the data you want to update/change is sorted to be at the top on both lists.
5. Now simply reapply the filter, but only filtering via the new column we created.  Since the data is now sorted properly, you should be able to simply select, copy, and paste your filtered source to your filtered destination.

If this answer was helpful to you, please mark it as accepted and up vote it.  Thanks!